# LINQ generating SqlException on VPS: "Timeout expired"

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, sqlexception

I want to do some reporting on my data, like pivot tables.

My Orders have OrderLines, which look roughly like this:

```
+----+---------+------------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+-----+
| Id | DistrId | ShipDestId | UnitPrice | DateCreated | OrderId | ProductId | Qty |
+----+---------+------------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+-----+
| 11 |     221 |        333 | 12.95     | 2015-01-24  |       4 |        12 |   3 |
| 12 |     221 |        333 | 12.95     | 2015-01-24  |       4 |        12 |   9 |
| 16 |     221 |        333 | 12.95     | 2015-01-25  |       5 |        12 |   3 |
| 17 |     221 |        333 | 12.95     | 2015-01-25  |       5 |        12 |   5 |
| 18 |     221 |        333 | 12.95     | 2015-01-25  |       5 |        12 |   2 |
| 19 |     221 |        333 | 14.95     | 2015-01-25  |       5 |        18 |   7 |
+----+---------+------------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+-----+
```

I want to use LINQ to generate JSON objects where I simplify my Order/OrderLines and Group them on Year, Month, Destination, Product, Region (omitted) and Division (omitted). So instead of pooping out 25,000 OrderLines, I want to condense it to 3,000 grouped rows.

The goal is to get it down to monthly calculated rows, instead of a huge number of individual daily order lines.

```
+------+-------+------+----------+-----------+--------+-----+
| Year | Month | Dest |   Dist   |  Product  | Amount | Qty |
+------+-------+------+----------+-----------+--------+-----+
| 2014 |    12 | NY   | XYZ, Ltd | Product A | 12.95  |   3 |
| 2015 |     1 | NY   | XYZ, Ltd | Product A | 51.8   |  19 |
| 2015 |     1 | NY   | XYZ, Ltd | Product B | 14.95  |   7 |
+------+-------+------+----------+-----------+--------+-----+
```

So after a lot of trial and error in LinqPad, I came up with this:

```
from o in orderLines
group o by new {
    o.Order.DateCreated.Year, 
    o.Order.DateCreated.Month, 
    Destination = o.Order.ShippingDestination.CompanyName,
    Distributor = o.Order.Distributor.CompanyName,
    Product = o.Product.ProductName,
    Region = o.Order.ShippingDestination.SalesContact.SalesRegion.Name ?? "No Region",
    Division = o.Order.ShippingDestination.SalesContact.SalesRegion.SalesDivision.Name ?? "No Division",
    Status = o.Order.OrderStatus
} into g 
select new {
    g.Key.Year,
    Month = (g.Key.Month == 1 ? "01 (Jan)" : 
            g.Key.Month == 2 ? "02 (Feb)" : 
            g.Key.Month == 3 ? "03 (Mar)" : 
            g.Key.Month == 4 ? "04 (Apr)" : 
            g.Key.Month == 5 ? "05 (May)" : 
            g.Key.Month == 6 ? "06 (Jun)" : 
            g.Key.Month == 7 ? "07 (Jul)" : 
            g.Key.Month == 8 ? "08 (Aug)" : 
            g.Key.Month == 9 ? "09 (Sep)" : 
            g.Key.Month == 10 ? "10 (Oct)" : 
            g.Key.Month == 11 ? "11 (Nov)" : "12 (Dec)"),
    g.Key.Destination,
    g.Key.Distributor,
    g.Key.Region,
    g.Key.Division,
    g.Key.Product,
    Cases = g.Sum (x => (Int32?)x.QuantityCases),
    Price = g.Sum (x => (Decimal?)x.UnitPrice * x.QuantityCases),
    Freight = g.Sum( x => x.Order.Freight ),
    g.Key.Status
};
```

This works exactly how I want it to, on my localhost in my ASP.NET WEB API and in LinqPad, but when I deploy my application to the server I'm waiting a long time and then I get:

```
"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An error occurred while reading from the 
store provider's data reader. See the inner exception for details."
...
"InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Timeout expired.  
The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.",
"ExceptionType":"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException","StackTrace":"   at 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, 
Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n   at 
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, 
Boolean asyncClose)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, 
SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, 
TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)\r\n   
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more)\r\n   
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()\r\n   
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.StoreRead()",
"InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":
"The wait operation timed out","ExceptionType":"System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception","StackTrace":null}}}
```

When I execute it in LinqPad then this is the generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[OrderStatus] AS [OrderStatus], 
    [Project1].[C3] AS [C1], 
    CASE WHEN (1 = [Project1].[C4]) THEN N'01 (Jan)' WHEN (2 = [Project1].[C4]) THEN N'02 (Feb)' WHEN (3 = [Project1].[C4]) THEN N'03 (Mar)' WHEN (4 = [Project1].[C4]) THEN N'04 (Apr)' WHEN (5 = [Project1].[C4]) THEN N'05 (May)' WHEN (6 = [Project1].[C4]) THEN N'06 (Jun)' WHEN (7 = [Project1].[C4]) THEN N'07 (Jul)' WHEN (8 = [Project1].[C4]) THEN N'08 (Aug)' WHEN (9 = [Project1].[C4]) THEN N'09 (Sep)' WHEN (10 = [Project1].[C4]) THEN N'10 (Oct)' WHEN (11 = [Project1].[C4]) THEN N'11 (Nov)' ELSE N'12 (Dec)' END AS [C2], 
    [Project1].[CompanyName] AS [CompanyName], 
    [Project1].[CompanyName1] AS [CompanyName1], 
    [Project1].[C5] AS [C3], 
    [Project1].[C6] AS [C4], 
    [Project1].[ProductName] AS [ProductName], 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C5], 
    [Project1].[C2] AS [C6], 
    [Project1].[C7] AS [C7]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1], 
        [GroupBy1].[A2] AS [C2], 
        [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [OrderStatus], 
        [GroupBy1].[K2] AS [CompanyName], 
        [GroupBy1].[K3] AS [CompanyName1], 
        [GroupBy1].[K4] AS [ProductName], 
        [GroupBy1].[K5] AS [C3], 
        [GroupBy1].[K6] AS [C4], 
        [GroupBy1].[K7] AS [C5], 
        [GroupBy1].[K8] AS [C6], 
        (SELECT 
            SUM([Extent21].[Freight]) AS [A1]
            FROM                   [dbo].[OrderLines] AS [Extent20]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent21] ON [Extent20].[OrderId] = [Extent21].[Id]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent22] ON ([Extent21].[ShippingDestinationId] = [Extent22].[Id]) AND ([Extent22].[Discriminator] = N'ShippingDestination')
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent23] ON ([Extent21].[DistributorId] = [Extent23].[Id]) AND ([Extent23].[Discriminator] = N'Distributor')
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent24] ON [Extent20].[ProductId] = [Extent24].[Id]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent25] ON ([Extent21].[ShippingDestinationId] = [Extent25].[Id]) AND ([Extent25].[Discriminator] = N'ShippingDestination')
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent26] ON ([Extent25].[ShippingDestination_SalesContactId] = [Extent26].[Id]) AND ([Extent26].[Discriminator] = N'SalesContact')
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[SalesRegions] AS [Extent27] ON [Extent26].[SalesRegionId] = [Extent27].[Id]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent28] ON ([Extent21].[ShippingDestinationId] = [Extent28].[Id]) AND ([Extent28].[Discriminator] = N'ShippingDestination')
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent29] ON ([Extent28].[ShippingDestination_SalesContactId] = [Extent29].[Id]) AND ([Extent29].[Discriminator] = N'SalesContact')
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[SalesRegions] AS [Extent30] ON [Extent29].[SalesRegionId] = [Extent30].[Id]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent31] ON ([Extent21].[ShippingDestinationId] = [Extent31].[Id]) AND ([Extent31].[Discriminator] = N'ShippingDestination')
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent32] ON ([Extent31].[ShippingDestination_SalesContactId] = [Extent32].[Id]) AND ([Extent32].[Discriminator] = N'SalesContact')
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[SalesRegions] AS [Extent33] ON [Extent32].[SalesRegionId] = [Extent33].[Id]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[SalesDivisions] AS [Extent34] ON [Extent33].[SalesDivisionId] = [Extent34].[Id]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent35] ON ([Extent21].[ShippingDestinationId] = [Extent35].[Id]) AND ([Extent35].[Discriminator] = N'ShippingDestination')
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent36] ON ([Extent35].[ShippingDestination_SalesContactId] = [Extent36].[Id]) AND ([Extent36].[Discriminator] = N'SalesContact')
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[SalesRegions] AS [Extent37] ON [Extent36].[SalesRegionId] = [Extent37].[Id]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[SalesDivisions] AS [Extent38] ON [Extent37].[SalesDivisionId] = [Extent38].[Id]
            WHERE (([GroupBy1].[K5] = (DATEPART (year, [Extent21].[DateCreated]))) OR (([GroupBy1].[K5] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART (year, [Extent21].[DateCreated]) IS NULL))) AND (([GroupBy1].[K6] = (DATEPART (month, [Extent21].[DateCreated]))) OR (([GroupBy1].[K6] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART (month, [Extent21].[DateCreated]) IS NULL))) AND (([GroupBy1].[K2] = [Extent22].[CompanyName]) OR (([GroupBy1].[K2] IS NULL) AND ([Extent22].[CompanyName] IS NULL))) AND (([GroupBy1].[K3] = [Extent23].[CompanyName]) OR (([GroupBy1].[K3] IS NULL) AND ([Extent23].[CompanyName] IS NULL))) AND ([GroupBy1].[K4] = [Extent24].[ProductName]) AND (([GroupBy1].[K7] = (CASE WHEN ([Extent27].[Name] IS NULL) THEN N'No Region' ELSE [Extent30].[Name] END)) OR (([GroupBy1].[K7] IS NULL) AND (CASE WHEN ([Extent27].[Name] IS NULL) THEN N'No Region' ELSE [Extent30].[Name] END IS NULL))) AND (([GroupBy1].[K8] = (CASE WHEN ([Extent34].[Name] IS NULL) THEN N'No Division' ELSE [Extent38].[Name] END)) OR (([GroupBy1].[K8] IS NULL) AND (CASE WHEN ([Extent34].[Name] IS NULL) THEN N'No Division' ELSE [Extent38].[Name] END IS NULL))) AND ([GroupBy1].[K1] = [Extent21].[OrderStatus])) AS [C7]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Join18].[K1] AS [K1], 
            [Join18].[K2] AS [K2], 
            [Join18].[K3] AS [K3], 
            [Join18].[K4] AS [K4], 
            [Join18].[K5] AS [K5], 
            [Join18].[K6] AS [K6], 
            [Join18].[K7] AS [K7], 
            [Join18].[K8] AS [K8], 
            SUM([Join18].[A1]) AS [A1], 
            SUM([Join18].[A2]) AS [A2]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Extent2].[OrderStatus] AS [K1], 
                [Extent3].[CompanyName] AS [K2], 
                [Extent4].[CompanyName] AS [K3], 
                [Extent5].[ProductName] AS [K4], 
                DATEPART (year, [Extent2].[DateCreated]) AS [K5], 
                DATEPART (month, [Extent2].[DateCreated]) AS [K6], 
                CASE WHEN ([Extent8].[Name] IS NULL) THEN N'No Region' ELSE [Extent11].[Name] END AS [K7], 
                CASE WHEN ([Extent15].[Name] IS NULL) THEN N'No Division' ELSE [Extent19].[Name] END AS [K8], 
                [Extent1].[QuantityCases] AS [A1], 
                [Extent1].[UnitPrice] *  CAST( [Extent1].[QuantityCases] AS decimal(19,0)) AS [A2]
                FROM                   [dbo].[OrderLines] AS [Extent1]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[OrderId] = [Extent2].[Id]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent3] ON ([Extent2].[ShippingDestinationId] = [Extent3].[Id]) AND ([Extent3].[Discriminator] = N'ShippingDestination')
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent4] ON ([Extent2].[DistributorId] = [Extent4].[Id]) AND ([Extent4].[Discriminator] = N'Distributor')
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent1].[ProductId] = [Extent5].[Id]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent6] ON ([Extent2].[ShippingDestinationId] = [Extent6].[Id]) AND ([Extent6].[Discriminator] = N'ShippingDestination')
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent7] ON ([Extent6].[ShippingDestination_SalesContactId] = [Extent7].[Id]) AND ([Extent7].[Discriminator] = N'SalesContact')
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[SalesRegions] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent7].[SalesRegionId] = [Extent8].[Id]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent9] ON ([Extent2].[ShippingDestinationId] = [Extent9].[Id]) AND ([Extent9].[Discriminator] = N'ShippingDestination')
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent10] ON ([Extent9].[ShippingDestination_SalesContactId] = [Extent10].[Id]) AND ([Extent10].[Discriminator] = N'SalesContact')
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[SalesRegions] AS [Extent11] ON [Extent10].[SalesRegionId] = [Extent11].[Id]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent12] ON ([Extent2].[ShippingDestinationId] = [Extent12].[Id]) AND ([Extent12].[Discriminator] = N'ShippingDestination')
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent13] ON ([Extent12].[ShippingDestination_SalesContactId] = [Extent13].[Id]) AND ([Extent13].[Discriminator] = N'SalesContact')
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[SalesRegions] AS [Extent14] ON [Extent13].[SalesRegionId] = [Extent14].[Id]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[SalesDivisions] AS [Extent15] ON [Extent14].[SalesDivisionId] = [Extent15].[Id]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent16] ON ([Extent2].[ShippingDestinationId] = [Extent16].[Id]) AND ([Extent16].[Discriminator] = N'ShippingDestination')
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent17] ON ([Extent16].[ShippingDestination_SalesContactId] = [Extent17].[Id]) AND ([Extent17].[Discriminator] = N'SalesContact')
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[SalesRegions] AS [Extent18] ON [Extent17].[SalesRegionId] = [Extent18].[Id]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[SalesDivisions] AS [Extent19] ON [Extent18].[SalesDivisionId] = [Extent19].[Id]
            )  AS [Join18]
            GROUP BY [K1], [K2], [K3], [K4], [K5], [K6], [K7], [K8]
        )  AS [GroupBy1]
    )  AS [Project1]
```

Comment: Wrong connection string?

Comment: No, the rest of the application works on the server. It is only this query. Also, it does work flawlessly on localhost.

Comment: Analyze the query execution plan, maybe a missing index slow down the query and generate the timeout.

Comment: What happen if you run the query directly in query editor? is the amount of data on the server same as locally?

Comment: I'm using the exact same database (exported locally and imported on the server). Both localhost and server use SQL Server 2012 Express. I deploy via Web Deploy. I would argue that both sides are equal (except IIS vs local)

Comment: @gsharp, I copied the query in the SQL Management Studio on both sides: localhost -> 7sec & server -> +5min (after which 10% was done). WOW! What could be the problem in server configs?

Comment: Can be anything, but i would look at the query execution plan like suggested from @Max  first. If you have a tool like Schema Compare you can do a diff from your localhost and server.